# Jenkins VM Crashed, now there are no jobs

Tags: hudson, jenkins

The VM that was running Jenkins for me crashed, and when I rebooted it there were no Jobs on Jenkins.  These weren't terribly complicated scripts, but it did take several hours to write is there any way I can recover them?  There are still directories in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs that contain the config.xml, but I don't know how to get jenkins to read these files?  Any help recovering these would be appreciated...

Comment: Also, if jenkins service crashes, it may be due to low memory and no swap. Running `sudo apt install swapspace` will give it dynamic memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manage jenkins -> reload configuration from disk